# Devise Send Reset Password Instruction "undefined method `slice' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using devise (2.2.3) in a rails (3.2.12) application.

I have 2 devise model, devise Admin and User
On devise model Admin authentication_keys using email and User authentication_keys using username (but still having email), admin model is fully working but user model on forgot password function has decided stop working. When I enter an email address and click the 'send me reset instructions', I got the error message looks like :

```
NoMethodError in PasswordusersController#create

undefined method `slice' for nil:NilClass
```

There is no significant differences between `passwordadmins_controller.rb` with `passwordusers_controller.rb` , the only difference being named

What I do I have to do to fix this?

This `passwordusers_controller.rb`

```
class PasswordusersController < Devise::PasswordsController

  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication
  append_before_filter :assert_reset_token_passed, :only => :edit

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      redirect_to new_session_user_path, :notice => "Instruction Send To Your Email"
    else
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end

  def edit
    super
  end

  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)

    if resource.errors.empty?
      resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
      flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
      set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      redirect_to home_subdomain_path, :notice => "Password changed"
    else
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  protected

    def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
      new_session_user_path
    end

    def assert_reset_token_passed
      if params[:reset_password_token].blank?
        set_flash_message(:error, :no_token)
        redirect_to new_session_user_path
      end
    end

    def unlockable?(resource)
      resource.respond_to?(:unlock_access!) &&
        resource.respond_to?(:unlock_strategy_enabled?) &&
        resource.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email)
    end

end
```

UPDATE

```
<%= form_for("User", :url => passwordusers_create_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'layouts/flash_messages' %>
   <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
      <%= f.email_field :email, 'style' => 'width:240px;', :placeholder => 'Email' %>
      </div>
     <div class="dr"><span></span></div>             
      <%= f.submit "Send", :class => 'btn btn-block btn-primary' %>
     <div class="dr"><span></span></div>                               
</div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Did you change the send_reset_password_instructions method in your (presumably) users model?

Comment: no, I did not change, user model working fully, but only `send_reset_password_instructions` not working. Now I'm looking for something that makes a mistake

Comment: can I see form forgot password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource devise default using lowercase, try this,

```
form_for("User" .....
```

change to

```
form_for("user"
```